# geom layer to set two categorical axes with points as count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am completing the exercises in Hadley Wickham's book ggplot2. There is a picture that the book asks to re-create:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)    
count <- mpg %>%
 group_by(drv, cyl) %>%
 summarise(n = n())
count
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cyl, y = drv)) +
 geom_point(aes(size = n), data = count, position = "jitter")
```

[image]
But it doesn't show the same picture. I cannot figure out which geom this plot is. But one thing is that the points in the plot could mean the count of observations that matches cyl and drv.

The data is mpg, which is included in tidyverse package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cyl, drv)) +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.05, 0.05))
```

By default jitter in `geom_jitter` is too large and we need to specify our own height and width of jitter by using `position_jitter` function.

[image]

Comment: Nice..thanks a lot. By the way, how did you figure out the position = position_jitter() argument?

Comment: @commentallez-vous I updated my answer. Play around with `position_jitter` function and it's numbers, it will be clearer how it works.

Comment: Or `geom_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0.05)`

Comment: @commentallez-vous If this solution solved your problem you can accept the answer.